# How to clear all selections in PowerBI?

Tags: business-intelligence, powerbi

In Qlikview we have clear all option to clear all the selections, what is the similar option in PowerBI?

Even Refreshing the report(using Refresh button in Home) doesn't work.

I read somewhere that refreshing the browser(in case of web) can clear all selections and restore the previous stage but it's not a feasible solution. Is there any alternate of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one-click button that will clear all slicer selections on an existing report.

As you've indicated in your question, you can do a browser refresh and the report will be reset back to its default state. You can also click away from the report and go back in, and the report will be reset back to its default state.

The "Refresh" button at the top of the report gets the latest data but does not reset the report back to its default state. Switching tabs within the report also does not reset the report back to its default state.

While this isn't the answer you want to hear, there are a couple of ideas I'd encourage you to comment & vote upon. I know Microsoft do pay close attention to submitted ideas:

1. [Clear All Slicers](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17413402-clear-all-slicers)
2. [Add Clear All Filters button to Power View**](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7201609-add-clear-all-filters-button-to-power-view)

** *While the idea specifically mentions Power View, it's clear from the comments that the same request applies to Power BI, the successor to Power View.*

Comment: Yes! Bookmarks weren't available when I posted this answer, but it's definitely the way to do it now.

Comment: Just wanted to update this in case anyone else stumbled upon it. It took me a while to figure this out, so just trying to spread the love ;)

Answer (score 7):

This can be accomplished by doing the following:

1. Create a bookmark with your default slicer selections
2. Ensure that "Display" is unchecked on the bookmark options
3. Upload an image that will serve as your refresh/clear-all button
4. Link the image to the book mark

Voila! Clear-all achieved